# Convert Data object from apollo hook call to Javascript Array

Tags: javascript, json, apollo, mobx

I am trying to convert the 'Data' structure element from apollo hook call to an array I can pass to render in React. Here is my hook call using the '@apollo/react-hooks' library. `const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(findTokenQuery)`

How can I convert the recieved Data structure element... {"id":4,"element":"TITANIUM","symbol":"TI"} to an array like [{id: 4, element:"TITANIUM",symbol:"TI"] ?

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the result in an array after it's destructured:

```
const arr = [data]
```

And then iterate over `arr`.